# Form Builder On the fly With asp.net mvc site

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Is there an open source form builder that I can add it to my MVC project and create form on the fly by it. I want to my users can create a series of form themselves and then MVC program to render them.

I saw http://www.wufoo.com and http://www.jotform.com and these are ideal form of my user story.

Answer (score 2):

Naked Objects is a .NET framework that takes a domain object model, written as POCOs but following a few very simple conventions, and dynamically creates one or more complete interfaces for it, using reflection (not 'code generation' or 'scaffolding').

Naked Objects MVC builds upon the core framework to create a complete web-based user interface, using ASP.NET MVC 4.

https://github.com/NakedObjectsGroup/NakedObjectsFramework

Answer (score -1):

I think you should check out Google Forms; It a free form builder with free hosting. It will save you allot of code writing that could use you for other stuff. 
For advance usage, search for how to add css and JS to google forms.

http://www.google.com/drive/apps.html

Comment: first at all thank you for your answer, but I want to create a form builder for my project to use end user. I want to end user can create form. thanks again